# How to make a title appear on a player screen on touching a block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building a map in Minecraft (Java Edition). How do we make it so that if a player touches or lands on a specific  block a title will appear on the screen? For example `/title @p title {"text":"Level 2","color":"red"}`. I want this to happen upon touching a block. But I want it to run once and never again, unless the player touches a red carpet or quarts. *This is what I want: a repeating system, basically a touching block system on touching a block, a title will appear and never again, but on touching another block the system will reset and we can touch that same block again.* Please tell me how to make this possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it wasn't clear what "Touching" a block means, I choose "Land on" as the solution

First, let us create a scoreboard to track which was the last stepped on block

```
/scoreboard objectives add last_stepped dummy
```

Here is the first command, let us call it [If statement], just to reference it later in this answer.

```
/execute as @a unless score @s last_stepped matches <N> at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:<YourBlock> run <Result>
```

Where [@a] is the players you want to target (You can learn more about [target selector here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Target_selectors)), [last_stepped] is the name of the scoreboard we created before, [N] is the ID we gave the block (We will choose an ID for each block later, this isn't any ingame actual ID), [YourBlock] is the block he has to stepon, and [Result] is our [/title] command or our [/scoreboard set] (Shown later).

This translates to "Execute as every player, if the block right bellow each player (Here, @s refers to self, or each player previously targeted, in this case, by the [as @a]) is [YourBlock], unless the last stepped block is the one we are looking for now, if so, run [Result] for each player"

(In case you are not familiar with command blocks) Set each command block as the following:

[image]

For each block you want to track, we will need two [Results]:

```
/execute <If statement> run title <your title command>

/execute <If statement> run scoreboard players set @s last_stepped <N>
```

Let me leave two examples here:

```
/execute as @a unless score @s last_stepped matches 1 at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:gold_block run title @s title {"text":"Level 1","color":"red"}
/execute as @a unless score @s last_stepped matches 1 at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:gold_block run scoreboard players set @s last_stepped 1

/execute as @a unless score @s last_stepped matches 2 at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:iron_block run title @s title {"text":"Level 2","color":"red"}
/execute as @a unless score @s last_stepped matches 2 at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:iron_block run scoreboard players set @s last_stepped 2
```

For the use of the OP:

```
/execute as @a unless score @s last_stepped matches 1 at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:polished_diorite run title @s title {"text":"Level 1","color":"red"}
/execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:polished_diorite run scoreboard players set @s last_stepped 1
/execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:red_carpet run scoreboard players set @s last_stepped 2
```

Comment: In which command do I put the command in like do i put the first command in the purple (repeat) command block and which mode do I set it in unconditional or conditional, need Redstone or always active. I think it is always active. Same question for the chain command block

Comment: The first command goes into the purple one, the second in the blue-greenish. Both to always active, and unconditional. Make sure that they are pointing in the correct direction as shown in the picture.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't play once. Basically when  I land on my block it says the title but when i just go backwards and forwards then it says it again I want it so it will only say it once and we can activate it again by touching another block. (I have attached a video link for more info or clear mind of what happening " https://youtu.be/LRE7LcUrUHE " )

Comment: This is exactly what this solution does. You might have done something wrong when coping the solution. Looking at your video, your first command has "Polished diorite" and the second "Red_carpet" when it is meant to be "Polished diorite" again. If you want the carpet to reset the scoreboard, have only the second line of the solution in a Blue command (or chainned to those 3) setting your score to something different to 1 (which refers to Polished diorite)

Comment: Editted the answer to your case specifically (You can still apply the solution normally, if done propelly, it will work). Also note that you are using @p in every target selector in your video, that means it will break if there is more than one person in the server and won't work with datapacks.

Comment: Did what you said still repeating titles https://youtu.be/P7UIhgI1BDE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129026/discussion-between-rayyan-and-bruno-rodrigues).

Comment: The title is on repeat when I land on my block (dirote block). Can you do a tutorial on how to do this with the red carpet resetting system and dirote block activating the title upon the player landing on it. But it will be active once. I did what you did, but it didn't work. Video For More Understanding: youtu.be/6Sd1ncsZfR4 . (Just make a full tutorial even those I did what you did maybe you will find the mistake if I have caused any.)

Comment: Your S in last_stepped is capital in your second command....... Also, for the carpet command, you need to have [~ ~ ~] instead of [~ ~-1 ~] since the latter refers to the block bellow you, but the carpet is at the same height as you.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!